# Nginx location for API requests and one location for all websockets requests

Tags: nginx

I use nginx as a reverse proxy and I have one server as API and Websocket server. In order to use WebScoket I need to specify some headers:

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

But, then I have some errors for API request and in order to fix it, I have to use:

```
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
```

But, the line above breaks websocket connection. So, I can fix it by several locations:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;           
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;           
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /someWebSocketUrl{
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location /anotherWebSocketUrl{
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location /oneMoreWebSocketUrl{
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

I don't like that I have to have separate location for every web socket url. Is it possible to simplify it? Something like:

```
location allWebSocketUrls_or_wss:// {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use for all statements:

```
location /websocketUrl {
    ...
}
```

For any location, which beginning as "/websocketUrl*". Or use regular expressions:

```
location ~ /(some|another|oneMore)?websocketUrl[1-3]*$ {
    ...
}
```

If you want exact urls. Or even simpler:

```
location ~ /.*websocketUrl.*$ {
    ...
}
```

which be used for any "websocketUrl". I think, it better to use special directory to all sockets, but this way will work too/

But if you have all same options, try to disable header:

```
location = / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;           
        proxy_set_header Connection "";  # <--- this will disable header
        proxy_set_header Host $host;           
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: The name `websocketUrl1-3` is just for example... Sorry, I had to mention it.